# TypeError: Cannot call method "show" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I see some sample code from other site and i see this but when i paste and run it's  have an error "TypeError: Cannot call method "show" of null. (line 5, file "

```
function hello() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('title Dude');
app.add(app.createLabel('Hello World'));
ss.show(app);
}
```

Can some help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script must be launch from a script within a spreadsheet and not a standalone script window. But anyway the UiApp service is deprecated since end of 2014 and you have to use [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html) to build user interface.
This code will no longer work.

Comment: so i cannot just run some code with js only? Sorry im new here.

Comment: Yes you can some js code but to display a pop up in the spreadsheet you have to use service from apps script. You can use html service and Browser.msgBox() https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/browser open a script window within spreadsheet and test piece of code from developper site to find what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you have no active spreadsheet ?

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
```

So it's return **null**

Comment: i already have an open sheet in my tab, should i refresh it before running the code or after i run the code?